# C++ returning GLM matrix from a function error: left of must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, glm-math

I am trying to return a GLM matrix from a function I've used in Java however in C++ it is giving me a "error C2228: left of '.createTransformationMatrix' must have class/struct/union"

Header file

```
#ifndef MATHS_H
#define MATHS_H

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glew.h> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Maths
{
public:

static glm::mat4 createTransformationMatrix(glm::vec3 translation, float 
       rx, float ry,float rz, float scale);
};
#endif
```

CPP file

```
#include"Maths.h"

glm::mat4 createTransformationMatrix(glm::vec3 translation, float rx, float   
     ry,float rz, float scale){

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4();
        //Do transformations
        return model;
 }
```

The error occurs when I call this function from an outside class like so. I'm not sure why I'm getting an error from doing this.

```
 glm::mat4 transformation = glm::mat4();
     transformation = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(      
 glm::vec3(entity.getPosition()),1,1,1,1);
```

Comment: If you have a class with only static public member functions, consider using a `namespace` instead. Then read about the scope operator `::`.

Answer (score 1):

As compared to Java, the syntax for using *static* members is a bit different in C++. Between the class-name and the static-member-name, you must use the *scope operator* `::` as shown below:

```
transformation = Maths::createTransformationMatrix(
    glm::vec3(entity.getPosition()),1,1,1,1);
```